# Springboot and thymealf loop

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

hope you can help with this simple noob problem. I creating a Multiple choice question using springboot and thymeleaf.I am getting this error and hope you can help me write the controller method.
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (learning:23)
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'options[0]' available as request attribute

```
 <form method="post" th:action="@{/list}" >
    <table>
        <tr th:each="option, rowStat : *{a}">
            <td><input type="radio" th:field="*{options[__${rowStat.index}__].ansA}" th:value="A"/></td>
            <td><input type="radio" th:field="*{options[__${rowStat.index}__].ansB}" th:value="B"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
</form>
```

Model object

```
@Entity
public class LearningStyle {
    private int Qid;
    private String question;
    private String ansA;
    private String ansB;
public LearningStyle(int qid, String question, String ansA, String ansB) {
    Qid = qid;
    this.question = question;
    this.ansA = ansA;
    this.ansB = ansB;
}

public LearningStyle(){}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "Qid", nullable = false, updatable = false)
public int getQid() {
    return Qid;
}

public void setQid(int qid) {
    Qid = qid;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getAnsA() {
    return ansA;
}

public void setAnsA(String ansA) {
    this.ansA = ansA;
}

public String getAnsB() {
    return ansB;
}

public void setAnsB(String ansB) {
    this.ansB = ansB;
}
```

}

Controller

```
public class LearningStyleController {
    @Autowired
    LearningStyleService learningstyleservice;




    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String learningstyle(Model model) {
       List<LearningStyle> a= learningstyleservice.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("a",a);
        return "learning";


    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String learn(@ModelAttribute("a") LearningStyle learningStyle, Model model) {

//code to get list of object
return "home";
}
```

Comment: i try this the error dissapear but my th:name is wrong here!!!                                                                              <table>
        <tr th:each="option, rowStat : *{a}">
            <td><input type="radio" th:for="|option${rowStat.index}|" th:name="ansA" th:value="A" />
            </td>
            <td><input type="radio" th:for="|option${rowStat.index}|" th:name="ansB" th:value="B"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

Comment: Where is th:name is being set ? and what it wrong ?